# translate string

Tags: i18n-l10n

On the site:
http://whayme.com/cleantheme/welkome-bij-whayme#

if you push the button for "Meld me aan" (Subscribe btn) WITHOUT a email address then a message will appear.

E-mail field is required.

I would like to change this message into "foo another message txt" but cannot find out how to do it. I already installed the stringoverrides module, but somehow this string is not matched. This modules works with other strings. Installed i18n but I don't want a second language. I just want a small adjustment.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think string overrides is not working because the error string is using a token of some kind.
Maybe try replacing "!name field is required." in string overrides.
I have not tested this btw.